# Alignment issue - spaces between the tags are very small

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design

The spaces between the tags are very small in the posts compared with the questions tab.

In the Questions tab:

> [image: Questions tab]

In the posts:

> [image: posts page]

**System Configuration:**
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro
Mozilla Firefox: 62.0 (64-bit)
Google Chrome: Version 69.0.3497.92 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Zoom: 100%

Comment: What browser are you using? Can’t reproduce in Chrome for iOS.

Comment: @alexolut System configuration added

Comment: Same bug presents on SO for me, but not on MSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the spaces between the tags are proper in the posts and as same as in the questions tab.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Proper space between tags]